# Is it possible to copy virtual machine from one computer(intel) to other computer (DELL)

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have a VM on my home computer.

Can i copy the virtual machine from home to my office PC.
That Hardware is different i  mean LAN card , graphics card will be different. But will that Work or not. I think VM can autodetect these

Comment: What sort of VM?  Is the software the same on both sides (eg, ESX at home, ESX at work)?

Comment: yes the software is same its vmware workstation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the answer is Yes.  You can run a VM on a different machine provided the architecture of the **VM** is the same.  If your VM is 64 bit with two CPUs then the VM on the new server must also be 64 bit and have two CPUs.  It doesn't matter what hardware the PC has so long as the virtual machine is the same on both boxes.  You don't need the same physical graphics/network/sound cards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely.  Should work flawlessly, as long as your not going from a new version of vmware workstation, to an older version.

Vmware will ask you if the vm is a move or a copy operation & if you select copy, it will generate things such as a new mac address inside the vmx file.